# Как сделать что бы браузер воспринимал кодировку изображений правильно?

Tags: php, сервер, кодировка, header

Вот так отдаю с помощью php картинку:

```
$file="http://site.net/1.jpg" ;

$filename = basename($file);
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

   switch( $file_extension ) {
      case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpeg"; break;
    default:
}



header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);


echo   readfile ($file);
```

Но вместо изображения значок пустой картинки. Если же скачать ее(эту, якобы пустую), открыть Нотепадом и указать, что кодировка ANSI, то она начинает открываться.
  Как сделать что бы браузер понимал, в какой кодировке нужно читать картинку?
  На локалке нормально работает- только на хостинге начались проблемы.

Comment: Похоже на ситуацию, когда php  уже что-то вывел и header игнорируется. Данный скрипт точно первый, кто отдает данные клиенту?

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов Да, точно- если попробовать что-то вывести до скрипта, то не картинка нулевая возвращается, а вывод+кракозябры.

Comment: А если еще добавить `header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');`?

Comment: Еще на локалке работает нормально, а когда на хостинг загрузил началось вышеописанное.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Не сработало- все так же... На сервере стоит Nginx, но отдача статического контента отключена, да и возвращает же картинку, и в той кодировке, только воспринимает браузер как другую кодировку- от чего вообще зависит в какой кодировке воспринимает браузер? В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Понятие кодировки для бинарного файла отсутствует. Какие заголовки принимает браузер, можете посмотреть?

Comment: В Хроме нажимаете F12, а потом идете [сюда](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E3SB.png), выбираете нужный файл и смотрите. Ну или дайте ссылку на ваш скрипт на хостинге

Comment: @AntonShchyrov В общем в файле подключения к БД- был вывод- стыдно за дурацкий вопрос. Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Лучше удалить вопрос или оставить- вы не новенький здесь- знаете вероятно.

Comment: Искали принципиально другую проблему. Об ошибке `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by` вы не сказали не слова. Более того, утверждали, что локально код работает. Т.е. в вопросе нет абсолютно ничего, что могло бы помочь кому-то еще. Так что удаляйте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле подключения к БД был вывод в буфер, что и стало причиной проблемы.

Comment: Стыдно быть не должно. Все совершают ошибки. Главное - это учиться на них ^_^

Answer (score 2):

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filename));
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
```

Попробуйте так

Comment: На скачку отдает, а нужно просто вывести, да и пустой файл почему-то скачивается.